# Android GridLayout Fitting Error

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Im trying to fit 4x4 buttons in grid layout which is in relativelayout.Everything is fine in virtual machine but on my galaxy s6, buttons which are in right doesnt fit well.
My XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/grey_wp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.uruskan.shock.myapplication.GameScreen">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="24sp" />
    <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
    >
    </GridLayout>
```

My Screenshoot from virtual machine
[image: virtualmachinescreenshoot]
My Screenshoot from real Galaxy S6
[image: galaxys6screenshoot]
How can I make this app looks like on emulator ?
Update :
I changed my emulator to Galaxy S6 and now its broken on emulator too.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
You need to use LayoutParameters in your Kart Class.

```
 GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED), GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1, 1f));
    params.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = 0;
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now It's fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use layout_weight=1 and layout_width=0dp on the widths of each cell, if they are imageViews, also add adjustViewBounds=true and scaleType=centerInside

Comment: They are buttons.(android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton)

Comment: I still need help

Comment: Try the layout_width=0 and layout_weight=1 stuff on the buttons and see if that helps. I've always been frustrated trying to get gridlayout to work how i want it too, so there are other options for layouts. If you know there will always be 16 buttons, you could just use a LinearLayouts, TableLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. Nested LinearLayouts would be the most straight forward

Comment: or you could just use ImageView instead of the buttons and make them look identical, and then try the scaling stuff i recommended

Comment: These buttons are my custom classes which i add to layout with java code so i dont know how im gonna set the layout specs you said.

Comment: I'm on vacation so I can't look this up for you but basically just add layout params programmatically to each view, and there is a 3rd parameter in the constructor for layout params that you can put 1f in for the weight. Just google add layout params programmatically

Comment: I made it by using weight and gravity things in gridlayout.Now my problem is Im generating these buttons from my custom class, and i dont know how to add layout parameters from java.